"Step up to your role" and "take over"
Does "step up to one's role" mean the same as "take over" in the following sentence :Ahmed is retiring and Anjali is stepping up to his role.

Metaphoric "stepping up" here means Anjali is being promoted / advancing his position, which is not implied by "taking over". A more senior (or equal) executive could "take over" someone else's role, but only a less senior executive could "step up" to the higher position.

Ahmed is retiring and Anjali is stepping up to his role.
This means that Ahmed is assuming the responsibilities that Anjali had. It doesn't necessarily mean that Ahmed is taking Anjali's job.
If you were to say:
Ahmed is retiring and Anjali is stepping into his role.
That would suggest that Ahmed is taking Anjali's job, like a promotion.


Ahmed is retiring and Anjali is stepping up to his role.

I add to what @FumbleFingers said.
The phrasal verb step up used in this sense is similar to this example, which relates to a promotion:

3
: to receive a promotion
She stepped up to the position of general manager.

With take over, there is no mention or implication of promotion:


PHRASAL VERB B2
If you take over a job or role or if you take over, you become responsible for the job after someone else has stopped doing it.


